# Laravel:insert variable sent by controller in eloquent query (99,5% of code completed)

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent

What I have done always in the past, also with Codeigniter is balking at me now. Need to insert the variable in the SQL query (PDO Eloquent style) but it complaints that "column not found", so in order to have it work I hardcoded it and it does return correct result, but of course, cant do with hardcoding. That is the question, what the syntax is to place a variable right where you are seeing the number 7. At the Controller what I have from an Ajax forwarding as thing to be sent is this:

```
$data['input']
```

so that is what I want to send to the Model

`$hospital['input'] = with(new treatment)->sendData(7);` (but I hardcoded a 7)

and this is the eloquent query:

```
<?php
class Treatment extends Eloquent {



    public function sendData(){

     $resultado = DB::table('treatments')
    ->whereIn('departamento', function($query)
    {
        $query->select(DB::raw('spec_description'))
              ->from('specialties')
              ->whereRaw('id_specialty = 7');
    })
    ->get();

        return $resultado;

    }


}
```

Thank you

Comment: I'm not 100% sure about this, but there is no data being returned in the closure so the whereIn doesn't appear to be getting the data it needs. you could try return the query data from the closure, hopefully that will sort out your problem

Comment: Hi. When I hardcode it and execute it, and look at the Firebug response, I can see it has yielded the right result from the database, so that is not an issue. The question is what the syntax is for placing a variable at the controller, where you can see the number 7, what that is for the parameter of the sendData() at the model and finally what you put in the query, where the number 7 is.

Answer (score 0):

You probably have to use `use ($id)`.

```
public function sendData(id)
{
    $resultado = DB::table('treatments')->whereIn('departamento', function($query) use ($id)
    {
        $query->select(DB::raw('spec_description'))->from('specialties')->where('id_specialty', $id);
    })->get();

    return $resultado;
}
```

It's also probably telling you column not found because you don't have the column `id_specialties` in your `specialties` table, but probably `id` instead.  But since you say it works with the hardcoded 7, I left it in the answer.

Comment: Hi, thank you for the input. I can see that you enter id as a parameter in the model page not including the $id. I do have a id_specialty as a name for the column but what interests me is the novelty that you indicated introducing id and not $id. Do you mean I am supposed to put in there the name of the column? and about the controller, what do I have to put as a parameter to send? if I ve got the data as $data['input']